# Swift iOS -Compare elements in 1 array by property

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of objects and I want to compare the objects based on property to find out if the properties are all the same. Right now I loop through all the objects, place all values of the properties in a separate array, and then use `filterArr.allSatisfy { $0 == filterArr.last }` to detemermine wether the properties are all the same or not.

This method works but I know there has to be a more elegant way then what I'm doing.

I actually went looking for an answer to this but every single thing I came across was comparing the elements of 2 different arrays instead of 1.

```
class IceCream {
    var flavor: String?
    var price: Double?
}

let iceCream1 = IceCream()
iceCream1.flavor = "vanilla"
iceCream1.price = 1.5

let iceCream2 = IceCream()
iceCream2.flavor = "chocolate"
iceCream2.price = 2.0

let iceCream3 = IceCream()
iceCream3.flavor = "vanilla"
iceCream3.price = 1.5

let iceCream4 = IceCream()
iceCream4.flavor = "strawberry"
iceCream4.price = 2.5

let iceCreams = [iceCream1, iceCream2, iceCream3, iceCream4]

var filterArr = [String]()

for iceCream in iceCreams {
    filterArr.append(iceCream.flavor ?? "")
}

let areItemsEqual = filterArr.allSatisfy { $0 == filterArr.last }

print(areItemsEqual) // prints false
```

Comment: Do you want to compare the price also or the flavor only ??

Comment: You shouldn't use classes unless you need reference semantics (doesn't seem to be the case here), `var` unless you need mutability, and optionals unless you need them. What do it mean for an `IceCream` to have a `nil` `flavour` and `price`?

Comment: @Sh_Khan Right now just the flavor is fine but you can always show 2 different ways to do it for other people

Comment: "This method works but I know there has to be a more elegant way then what I'm doing" Sorry, but why is what you're doing not elegant? An `allSatisfy` comparison with an arbitrary element is _exactly_ how to know whether they are all the same.

Comment: @Alexander I was trying to make it simple. I'm sending these objects to firebase and in the actual class declaration I have convenience initializer that takes in a dictionary which then gives those properties values. Some of the actual properties will have values and other will definitely be nil depending on what the user enters. For example if they don't have a middle name it will be nil. If they decide to exclude their gender it will be nil

Comment: @matt Hey there! I figured it wasn't elegant because I had to create a separate array to filter on. It seemed like I should just be able to do the filtering on the iceCreams array instead.

Comment: Lol really ghetto solution: `Set(iceCreams.lazy.map { $0.flavor}).count == 1`

Comment: @Alexander that solution worked. Why didn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @LanceSamaria Because it's horrible. Space complexity is `O(n)` in the worst case, and it never short circuits. Even if the first 2 elements are found to differ, it won't know to care, so it'll go through all `n` remaining elements to build the set, only to find out its count is > 1 and discard the set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid having to initialize and then assign the properties on separate lines with a struct.

```
struct IceCream {
    let flavor: String?
    let price: Double?
}

let iceCreams: [IceCream] = [
    IceCream(flavor: "vanilla", price: 1.5),
    IceCream(flavor: "chocolate", price: 2.0),
    IceCream(flavor: "vanilla", price: 1.5),
    IceCream(flavor: "strawberry", price: 2.5)
]
```

Using the generics sugar provided by [@Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander) and [@matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt), we have a nice looking extension.

```
extension Collection {
    func allEqual<T: Equatable>(by key: KeyPath<Element, T>) -> Bool {
        return allSatisfy { first?[keyPath:key] == $0[keyPath:key] }
    }
}

print(iceCreams.allEqual(by: \.flavor))
```

---

Alternatively, you could specify an `IceCream` be equal to one another by flavor.

```
extension IceCream: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: IceCream, rhs: IceCream) -> Bool {
        return lhs.flavor == rhs.flavor
    }
}

extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    func allEqual() -> Bool {
        return allSatisfy { first == $0 }
    }
}

print(iceCreams.allEqual())
```

Comment: I'm trying it now

Comment: @LanceSamaria 

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty Swifty way to do it. I define an extension on `Collection` that checks for equality among the collection's items, according to a given predicate:

```
extension Collection {
    func allEqual<T: Equatable>(by deriveKey: (Element) -> T) -> Bool {
        guard let firstElement = self.first else {
            return true // empty lists are all-equal
        }
        let sampleKey = deriveKey(firstElement)
        return self.dropFirst().allSatisfy{ deriveKey($0) == sampleKey }
    }
}

struct IceCream {
    let flavor: String
    let price: Double
}

let iceCreams = [
    IceCream(flavor:    "vanilla", price: 1.5),
    IceCream(flavor:  "chocolate", price: 2.0),
    IceCream(flavor:    "vanilla", price: 1.5),
    IceCream(flavor: "strawberry", price: 2.5)
]

let allItemsEqualByFlavour = iceCreams.allEqual(by: { $0.flavor})
print(allItemsEqualByFlavour) // false

let vanillaOnlyIceCreams = iceCreams.filter{ $0.flavor == "vanilla" }
print(vanillaOnlyIceCreams.allEqual(by: { $0.flavor})) // true
```

Comment: I was trying the other guys first while you was entering yours so it's only fair. I'm going to try yours now and upvote it if it works.

Comment: even Xcode when I added the allEqual function to the Collection extension I get the same error I got in Playgrounds: Default argument value of type '(_) -> _' cannot be converted to type '(Self.Element) -> T' specifically on this: {$0}

Comment: @LanceSamaria Take that `= {$0}` part out. I was playing with it, didn't mean to post it as my answer. That syntax *is* possible, but you need a separate extension on `Collection where Element: Equatable`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elegant way to make sure your ice creams are the same along any arbitrary axis, i.e. either flavor or price or any other equatable property you may later inject:

```
extension Array {
    func allSameForProperty<T:Equatable> (_ p:KeyPath<Element,T>) -> Bool {
        return self.isEmpty || self.allSatisfy{
            self.first![keyPath:p] == $0[keyPath:p]
        }
    }
}
```

Let's test it. First, some initial conditions:

```
struct Icecream {
    let flavor : String
    let price : Double
}
let arr = [
    Icecream(flavor: "vanilla", price: 1.5),
    Icecream(flavor: "vanilla", price: 1.75)
]
```

And now the actual test:

```
arr.allSameForProperty(\Icecream.flavor) // true
arr.allSameForProperty(\Icecream.price) // false
```

Comment: I'll try it in a few minutes and get back to you. Nice option to be able to compare on both properties if it works.

Comment: what's the reason for the backslash in front of \Icecream? I've never seen that before unless it's string interpolation

Comment: @matt I like the use of `KeyPath`, but I *really* wish Swift provided a bridging mechanism between keypaths and closures :(

Comment: Oof, really not a fan of capturing `arr` as an implicit arg. Better to just make it explicit, or better yet, make it an extension as I did

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I wasn't finished yet. Now I'm pretty much finished. :)

Comment: @LanceSamaria The backslash forms a key path, which is the entire point of my approach.